# Jsoup getting data form table depending on the color

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

I need to get data (actual - gray and forecast capacity - green) from table http://www.mercado.ren.pt/EN/Electr/MarketInfo/Interconnections/CapForecast/Pages/Daily.aspx

I'm using Jsoup and I don't know how to get capacity depending on the color. Worst I can't even find color in XML.

The HTML code looks like this:

```html
<table class="gridALL" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th align="left" colspan="2">
      <A id='helpTimePeriod' href='/EN/pages/TimePeriods.aspx' target='_blank'>
        <span class='txtDATA'>HOURS</span>
        <span style='vertical-align: 13%;' class='icon-info'>&nbsp;</span>
      </A>
    </th>
    <th align="left" valign="middle" colspan="29">Import Capacity</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tabHEADER">
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">HOUR</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">26&nbsp;May</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">27&nbsp;May</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">28&nbsp;May</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">29&nbsp;May</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">30&nbsp;May</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">31&nbsp;May</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">01&nbsp;Jun</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">02&nbsp;Jun</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">03&nbsp;Jun</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">04&nbsp;Jun</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">05&nbsp;Jun</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">06&nbsp;Jun</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">07&nbsp;Jun</th>
    <th class="rbcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">08&nbsp;Jun</th>
    <th class="bcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" scope="col">09&nbsp;Jun</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="trPAR">
    <td class="rcellBDRCOLOR" align="right" width="50">1</td>
    <td class="txtrVERIF" align="right" width="60">2700</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2700</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2700</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2700</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2700</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2700</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2700</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2700</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2400</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2400</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2400</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2400</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2400</td>
    <td class="txtrPREV" align="right" width="60">2400</td>
    <td class="txtPREV" align="right" width="60">2400</td>
  </tr>
```

Is it possible to get this fields using Jsoup lib?

Edit:

As far I have this, for now:

```js
doc = Jsoup.connect(path).get();
for (Element table: doc.select("table.gridALL")) {
  for (Element row: table.select("tr")) {
    Elements tds = row.select("td");
    if (tds.size() >= 16) {
      String record = tds.get(column).text();
      String recordColor = tds.get(column).attr("class");
```

I can only get attribute(txtrVERIF/txtrPREV) or capacity. How to get capacity depending on attribute? What condition should I give?

Comment: Colors are defined in [CSS](http://www.mercado.ren.pt/Style%20Library/pt-pt/Core%20Styles/gmREN.css).

Comment: Do your gray and green capacity values correspond to the "class" attribute for each row?  If so, you could extract what you need based on that value rather than the colors mapped to them.